# How to merge offline Firebase database version with the online one

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i merge the offline version of firebase database that is on an android device with the online version such that any node added offline under a certain root will always be inserted after any node of the online version regardless of the the time it was added at.

Example:

if (root x) has the following nodes in order: (a, b), if the offline version added a node c then the online version added node d, then after merging both the order will be (a, b, c, d). how can i achieve the order(a, b, d, c)?

Comment: The bigger question here is why is that important? With a proper structure it won't matter when the nodes where created as child nodes would determine the order.

Comment: @Jay Because i am implementing a chat application. So, if a user was offline and sent messages, then turned online, his messages will be inserted in between other messages not at the bottom of the root node, hence, i would have to sort the list in some way each time i display the messages to the other user to make them appear at the bottom.

Comment: Is this not a matter of tracking the timestamp of when the message was sent **to the server** as opposed to tracking the time when the message was sent **by the user**?

Comment: Ordering is Firebase is a pretty straightforward task (orderBy) so that would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening by default in `Firebase`. When you are offline and you make some changes in your app, when you'll be back online, all the changes that were made during that period will be updated on Firebase servers according with the data and time of the change.

To enable this option you can use this line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, i know. But as mentioned in my question above, i don't want the nodes to be ordered by their insertion date (a, b, c, d), instead, how can i achieve (a, b, d, c)?

Comment: You cannot achieve that. In your Firebase database, childrens are added as explained above. If you want to display them in your app, you can order them as you like, using one of the methods provided by Firebase like: `orderByChild`, `orderByKey` or `orderByValue`.